# _beginthread vs CreateThread

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

What is the difference between CreateThread and beginthread APIs in Windows? Which one is preferrable for thread creation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`_beginthread()` and `_beginthreadex()` was required by earlier versions of the Microsoft CRT to initialize thread-local state.  The `strtok()` function would be an example.  That's been fixed, that state now gets dynamically initialized, at least since VS2005.  Using `CreateThread()` no longer causes problems.

Comment: Yes - if a thread is created using `CreateThread()` then `strtok()` will allocate the per-thread-data block. However when the thread exits, that block will be leaked. Might not be a big deal, but why not just use `_beginthreadex()` in the first place?  Also, for the new "packaged applications", `_beginthreadex()` (from VS 2012) will make sure the MTA is initialized in the new thread.  Why not have programmers get into the habit of using `_beginthreadex()` (which really has no downside compared to using `CreateThread()` - it even has basically the same signature).

Comment: @Michael - check the CRT source code, look for the way it uses FlsAlloc() to install a callback to release memory.  Not being able to use the CRT in threadpool threads is of course not an acceptable limitation.