# How to start a thread with _beginthreadex?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I read on stackoverflow that when using the Windows API to start a thread `_beginthreadex()` is preferred over `CreateThread()`.

I am creating threads like this using `CreateThread()`:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* data)
{
    // code for the thread functionality.
}

 HANDLE Multicast = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);
 if (Multicast) { } // thread started successfully.
```

How do I do this with `_beginthreadex()` rather than `CreateThread()`?

Can anyone post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL,0,NULL);
```

should do the trick for you. You can ignore those additional parameters as most of those are optional.

The following SO links might be useful for you:

[Windows threading: _beginthread vs _beginthreadex vs CreateThread C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c)

[_beginthread vs CreateThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100589/beginthread-vs-createthread)